# Hölder's inequality different condition for equality ($L^p$ space)

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality

I came across this condition for equality for Hölder's of which I would like to know  proof of. Equality holds if and only if $A \vert f \vert^{p-1} = B \vert g \vert$ for non negative $A,B$ not both zero. (I was under the impression that there is only $\vert f \vert^p = C \vert g \vert^q$ for which the proof is clear).

Any help is appreciated

Comment: @DavideGiraudo How does one go about proving equivalence of the two conditions?

Comment: Hint: $q=\frac{p}{p-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exponents are conjugate, so $p+q=pq$. If we take the first condition, then $A^q|f|^{p+q-q}=B^q|g|^q$ (after having took the exponent $q$). Take the power $\frac 1q$ to get the opposite direction.